# I need to solve a Truth Table question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem and I need to solve it, thank you from now..

An enormous amount of loot had been stolen from a store. The criminal (or criminals) took the heist away in a car. Three well-known criminals, A, B, and C, were brought to the police station for questioning. The following facts were determined:

1) No one other than A,B, or C was involved in the robbery.

2) C never pulls a job with using A and (possibly others) as an accomplice.

3) B does not know how to drive

Use truth table to determine if A is innocent or guilty?

Comment: I did notice that.  But I didn't want to confuse the issue.

Comment: If we interpret it as never *with* than A's guilt or innocence can not be confirmed.  Either A did it alone, A did it with B, B did it with C, or C did it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

If $\;A\;$ is innocent then $\;C\;$ also is innocent so it **must be** that $\;B\;$ **alone** is guilty, which is impossible as he can't drive and the guilty one(s) drove away in a car. Ergo, $\;A\;$ must be guilty.

Now justify by the given info the above claims and deductions.

Answer (score 0):

If B is not guilty, then C or A must have been in the crime. If it were just A then A is guilty. If it were just C, well then A had to be long with C so A is guilty, by (2).

If B is guilty, then he was not the driver. Then, if A was the driver, then A is guilty. If C was the driver, then he was in on the crime, and by (2), so was A. Therefore A is guilty.

A is guilty ez life sentence

Answer (score 0):

Truth tables not efficient but ... here goes

1) A not involved B not involved C not involved.

Impossible as at least one was involved.

2) A not involved B not involved C involved.

Impossible as C never works without A.  So this also rules out:

3) A not involve B involved C involved.

4) A not involved B involved C not involved.

Impossible as B can't drive so B can't do it alone.

Those are all the cases in which A was not involved.

The only remaining possibilities all have A involved.

So A is involved.

5) A involved; B not; C not

6) A involved; B not; C involved

7) A involved; B involved; C not

8) A involved; B involved; C involved

All possible.